# Unable to setup HTTPS for Wordpress in Google Cloud VM

Tags: wordpress, https, google-cloud-platform

I'm following this [tutotial](https://onepagezen.com/free-ssl-certificate-wordpress-google-cloud-click-to-deploy/) to setup HTTPS in my Wordpress site (www.healthiness.shop), but I'm not able to access the site anymore. How can I fix this?

This is /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

```
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            <VirtualHost _default_:443>
                    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
                    <Directory /var/www/html/>
                    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                    AllowOverride All
                    Order allow,deny
                    allow from all
                    </Directory>
                    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ...

#SSLCertificateFile     /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
                #SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
                SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/healthiness.shop/cert.pem"
                SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/healthiness.shop/privkey.pem"
                SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/healthiness.shop/chain.pem"
```

This is /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ServerName www.healthiness.shop
ServerAlias healthiness.shop
Redirect permanent / https://www.healthiness.shop/
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

When I run

```
curl -i http://www.healthiness.shop/
```

This is the result

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Sat, 04 Apr 2020 18:04:46 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://www.healthiness.shop/
Content-Length: 237
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://www.healthiness.shop/">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

When I run

```
curl -i https://www.healthiness.shop/
```

I get no answer in console

When I run

```
curl -i http://35.188.74.178
```

I get the normal html page

When I run

```
ping healthiness.shop
```

I get

```
PING healthiness.shop (35.188.74.178) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- healthiness.shop ping statistics ---
50 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 50179ms
```

When I run

```
ping www.healthiness.shop
```

I get

```
PING healthiness.shop (35.188.74.178) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- healthiness.shop ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5126ms
```

When I run

```
filipe_ferminiano@wordpress-1-vm:~$ sudo service apache2 restart
filipe_ferminiano@wordpress-1-vm:~$ sudo service apache2 status
```

I get

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-04-04 19:15:29 UTC; 8s ago
  Process: 22132 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10726 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 22139 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 22144 (apache2)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─22144 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22145 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22146 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22147 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─22148 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─22149 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Apr 04 19:15:29 wordpress-1-vm systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Apr 04 19:15:29 wordpress-1-vm systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Apr 04 19:15:29 wordpress-1-vm systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Here are the firewall rules that I have. I aded a 443 port, but still not working
[image: Ports]

Comment: Post the result from these commands in your question: 1) `curl -i http://www.healthiness.shop/` 2) `curl -i https://www.healthiness.shop/` 3) Get the public IP address and run this command `curl -i http://IP-ADDRESS/` 4) `ping healthiness.shop` 5) `ping www.healthiness.shop`

Comment: @JohnHanley I edited the question with the answers. Can you check please?

Comment: 1) I am leaning towards the Apache SSL module is not set up correctly. 2) Restart Apache and post the entire output. `sudo service apache2 restart` and `sudo service apache2 status`.

Comment: @JohnHanley Updated the question with the output requested

Comment: Show the Google Cloud Firewall rules for this VM instance. I think you are missing an allow rule for port 443.

Comment: @JohnHanley you were right. I was missing an allow rule for 443 port. I added it and updated my question with a screenshot. But it's still not working

Comment: 1) You show different targets for port 80 and port 443. Why? 2) Have you enabled the internal Linux firewall? 3) For this VM instance what `Network tags` are assigned? 4) For the port 443 rule which instances show under "VPC network" -> "Firewall rules" -> Applicable to instances"?

Comment: Why don't you just go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> click on `NAME_OF_YOUR_INSTANCE` -> click `EDIT` -> go to `Firewall` ->  and check `Allow HTTP traffic` and `Allow HTTPS traffic` instead of creating your own firewall rules?